# Windows 8 URI Launcher won't launch image and document paths

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

I'm trying to launch a file (document, picture,...) from my Windows 8 app using the Launcher API but the file won't open with the default program associated with it.

Following code runs when clicked on a file:

`AttachedFile file = e.ClickedItem as AttachedFile;`

`bool isLaunched = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.Absolute));
//isLaunched is false`

The specified path is an absolute path that works when pasting it into the File Explorer. (C:\Users...\file.txt)

Using the Launcher with a StorageFile returns an error because the app doesn't have the permissions to edit the file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a programmatic access to the files outside of the local folder or the libraries? Sorry, there is no API for this.

```
   var fold = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary; 

   var f1 = await fold.GetFileAsync("hi.txt");       
   var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
   options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
   bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(f1, options);
```

Should add "capability in manifest", to use KnownFolders like DocumentLibrary,PictureLibrary,MusicLibrary...

Source:http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2011/10/03/winrt-storage-overview